# iOS Localization Troubles

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm currently trying to localize my iOS app into French. For some reason my keys aren't being properly recognized. My `.strings` french file looks like this:

```
"START_FLIGHT" = "Démarrez";
"STOP_FLIGHT" = "Arrêtez";
```

But when I call:

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("STOP_FLIGHT", comment: "Stop Flight")
StartandStop.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The title of the button is changed to `STOP_FLIGHT`, where I intended the title to become `Arrêtez`. What have I got wrong?

Comment: have you verified the "strings" file is in UTF16LE encoding, with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). In terminal , execute this `hexdump -C -n 16 en.lproj/MyFile.strings ` to see if the first two bytes are `ff fe`

Comment: I wasn't aware that they had to be encoded in UTF16LE so I went ahead and changed them but when I compile the app I get `The data couldn't be read because it's in the incorrect format`.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't pointing to the right direction.

If you are using Swift and developing an iOS App, I assume you are using Xcode and interface builder, please see this picture for a hint of implement localization in Interface Builder http://cl.ly/image/113f3q0G0S0F

Comment: It will build if they are encoded as regular old UTF16 but the problem persists. Thanks anyways!

Comment: try delete the app in device or simulator and run again, I encountered this issue before where the app is picking up changes in the localization file

Comment: I reinstalled the app and the problem persists. I tried reinstalling with both aforementioned encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out :)

You have to specify the tableName (which is the Storyboard name, in most cases), like these, either works

```
    let titleStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey("STOP_FLIGHT", value: "default stop flight", table:"Main")
    let anotherTitle = NSLocalizedString("STOP_FLIGHT", tableName: "Main", comment: "Comment")
```

Comment: Actually I've just figured out that the problem arose from the naming of my `.strings` file. Thanks for helping out though :)

Comment: If thats helpful, plz kindly give me an UP && answer mark. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that localized string files can only be of the form `Localizable.strings` whereas I had named mine `Localization.strings`.

Comment: Yes, if you don't give the tableName which is the name of Storyboard, you have to put the localized string into `Localizable.strings`. Hope this helps.